# DHCP DNS DualServer configuration error: Server is not authorized

Tags: dns, replication, dhcp

I'm currently using [Dual DHCP DNS Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/) for my project to do replications and failover within my network system.

I followed the instructions clearly on doing Zone replications, but I keep getting an error message on "Server is not authorized". Thus I am unable to replicate my configurations from the primary sever to the secondary server.

This is the excerpt from my config.ini in the DUAL DHCP DNS Server folder.

> [ZONE_REPLICATION]
>
> Primary=192.168.20.1
>
> Secondary=192.168.20.2

Does anyone know what this is caused by? Firewall/Wrong configurations, etc?

[image: Debug Mode]

Answer (score 0):

Under the section [DOMAIN_NAME] You should put the domain name as:-

[DOMAIN_NAME]
landed.com=168.192.in-addr.arpa

The second part (168.192.in-addr.arpa) is reverse zone, based on your subnet. Both these parts are required for an authorized operation and authorized servers can only do replication.